# What is the proper procedure for error checking chunks in file transfer over HTTP?

Tags: node.js, http, mbed, chunking

My goal: transfer a large (~200k) binary file over HTTP in chunks and validate with some type of error detection that my received chunk (client side) is EXACTLY the same as the sent chunk from the server.

So I have a binary file (firmware update for a micro controller) that I'm trying to send from my server (nodejs with Express) to my device. I can successfully make HTTP requests for strings and other small things and read the responses fine, but now I want to send a file.

This file is roughly 200kb large, and on the server side I'm using `fseek` to split the file into chunk of 512 bytes (this is the page size of my onboard NAND flash that the update will be written to). On the client side (my microcontroller), I'm making a get request and specifying the index of the current chunk I'm on (e.g. I start at `?index=0` and increase chunk by chunk until around `?index=400`).

For each chunk I receive, I would like validate that I have the same data as the server. My current idea is to perform a CRC check on client side and compare it to the CRC from the server which will be stored in the header of the GET response. Is this a good approach? Is there a better standard out there for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Extra: Microcontroller uses an STM32 processor, 2MB of NAND flash, 256KB of SRAM. Writing my images using Mbed-OS 5.12

Comment: FWIW. TCP is already doing CRC32 on every packet sent. So doing another round of CRC32 would not gain you significantly better error detection. Use a better hash like MD5 or SHA1 (MD5 is less CPU intensive)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending the data via a single TCP socket, the channel ensures all sent data arrives at the remote end and will automatically recover from most errors without intervention using checksums and sequence numbers.

Splitting the data into chunks like this merely duplicates functionality already present in the TCP stack in a costly and inefficient manner.

As long as you check that there are no unrecoverable errors at the receiving end, and that the protocol you run on top of TCP has a means of identifying the start and end of the file (assuming you are using a protocol which may send other information over the same socket) the only thing you need to worry about is a man in the middle attack. How you deal with a man in the middle attack is a more complex proposition, and the right solution depends on your threat models.

OTOH if you are using a datagram based transport like UDP, it will be more efficient to use forward error correction than relying on checksums.

Answer (score 0):

Over HTTP(S) you cant validate chunks (unless they are not separate requests) = you can only add CRC or MD5 to the file and script on the server side can check it and send you the reply when the.

You have two options: 
1. Sen chunks as a separate requests (or files) and check the integrity of the chunk
2. Establish non HTTP connection and implement your own protocol sending
3. Use other file transfer protocols over TCP/IP